# Domain where the fractional Laplacian operator is a closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the fractional Laplacian defined by

$$(-\Delta)^s u(x) = P.V. \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}dy, \ s \in (0,1).$$
Also consider that

$$D((-\Delta)^s) = \{u \in H^s(\Omega); (-\Delta)^su \in L^2(\Omega)\},$$

for some $s \in (0,1)$.
I want to show that the operator $(-\Delta)^s : D((-\Delta)^s) \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ is closed. Here, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded and smooth domain with $u = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^N \backslash \Omega$.

**Attempt:**

Let $(u_n) \subset D((-\Delta)^s) $ with $u_n\to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $(-\Delta)^su_n \to v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ . By Fatou's Lemma, I was able to show that $u \in D((-\Delta)^s)$.
To show that $(-\Delta)^su = v$ a.e on $\Omega$, observe that since $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, there is a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ such that $u_{n_k} \to u$ a.e on $\Omega$ and $g \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $|u_{n_k}| \leqslant g$ a.e. on $\Omega$. Thus

$$\frac{u_{n_k}(x) - u_{n_k}(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}} \to\frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}} 
 \ \mbox{a.e} \ on \ \Omega.$$
But, to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem and show that

$$\int_{\Omega} \frac{u_{n_k}(x) - u_{n_k}(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}dy \to \int_{\Omega} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}dy,$$

we need to show that the above integrand is dominated by an integrable function. For example, we have

$$\frac{|u_{n_k}(x) - u_{n_k}(y)|}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}\leqslant \frac{g(x) + g(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}} 
 \ \ \mbox{a.e} \ \ on \ \ \Omega \ \ \mbox{and for all} \ \ n \in \ \mathbb{N}.$$

But there is no guarantee that the function $\frac{g(x) + g(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}} $ is integrable due to the singularity of $\frac{1}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}$. Or is there?

Comment: Quick clarification: What is your definition of $H^s(\Omega)$?

Comment: Hi, the definition is: $H^s(\Omega) = \left\{u\in L^2(\Omega) ;\int\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}dxdy<\infty \right\}$ equipped with the norm  $\|u\|_{H^s(\Omega)}=\left(\int_\Omega|u|^2 dx+\int\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}dxdy\right)^{\frac12}.$

Comment: My guess would be that pointwise convergence is too much to ask. I'd try to show something like $\langle (-\Delta)^s u, \varphi\rangle = \langle v,\varphi\rangle$, where the brackets denote the $L^2$ pairing, and equality holds for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: First thank you very much, Jose. Why showing that this holds for all $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ the equality $(-\Delta)^s u = v$ hold ?

Comment: If an $L^2(\Omega)$ function $g$ satisfies $\langle g, \varphi\rangle=0$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, then $g=0$ (the only function orthogonal to a dense subspace is the zero function).

Comment: @Jose27, 
thanks for your help. It really works to do what you suggested. However, it works only when we know that $u \in D((-\Delta)^s)$. But I found a problem when showing that $\int_\Omega |(-\Delta)^s u(x)|^2dx < \infty$. I opened up a new post, if you could take a look I would be very grateful.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710737/show-that-the-fractional-laplacian-operator-is-closed