# Show that the fractional Laplacian operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the fractional Laplacian defined by

$$(-\Delta)^s u(x) = P.V. \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}dy, \ s \in (0,1).$$
Also consider that

$$D((-\Delta)^s) = \{u \in H^s(\Omega); (-\Delta)^su \in L^2(\Omega)\},$$

for some $s \in (0,1)$.
I want to show that the operator $(-\Delta)^s : D((-\Delta)^s) \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ is closed. Here, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded and smooth domain with $u = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^N \backslash \Omega$.

**Attempt:**

Let $(u_n) \subset D((-\Delta)^s) $ with $u_n\to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $(-\Delta)^su_n \to v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ . By Fatou's Lemma, I was able to show that $u \in H^s(\Omega)$, where

$$H^s(\Omega) = \left\{u \in L^2(\Omega); \int \int_{\Omega \times \Omega}\frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x - y|^{(N + 2s)}}\right\}.$$

Now, I need to show that $\int_{\Omega}|(-\Delta)^su(x)|^2 dx < \infty$.
I have tried in different ways, but without success. For example, the most I can do is show, by Fatou's Lemma, that $\int_{\Omega}|(-\Delta)^su(x)|^2 dx \geqslant \|v\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

Comment: It looks like the exponent in the denominator for your $H^s$ norm is incorrect. Once you fix this it should follow immediately from Minkowski’s Integral Inequality https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality

Comment: @Nick, Thanks a lot for the correction, it was a typo.
Even with the suggested inequality I have not been successful. The closest I can get is using Fatou's Lemma, but it gives me an inequality contrary to the desired meaning. The Donined Convergence Theorem also seems infeasible because of the non-integrability of the function $J(x) = |x|^{-(N+ 2s)}$.